# Maven proguard-maven-plugin duplicate class definitions and incorrectly named files

Tags: java, maven, proguard, proguard-maven-plugin

I'm trying to use `proguard-maven-plugin` with `proguardVersion 6.0.3`. This is plugin declaration in pom.xml:

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>com.github.wvengen</groupId>
    <artifactId>proguard-maven-plugin</artifactId>
    <executions>
        <execution>
            <phase>package</phase>
            <goals>
                <goal>proguard</goal>
            </goals>
        </execution>
    </executions>
    <configuration>
        <proguardVersion>6.0.3</proguardVersion>
        <injar>${project.build.finalName}.jar</injar>
        <outjar>${project.build.finalName}.jar</outjar>
        <obfuscate>true</obfuscate>
        <options>
            <option>-dontshrink</option>
            <option>-dontoptimize</option>
            <!-- This option will replace all strings in reflections method invocations with new class names. For example, invokes Class.forName('className') -->
            <option>-adaptclassstrings</option>
            <!-- This option will save all original annotations and etc. Otherwise all we be removed from files. -->
            <option>-keepattributes Exceptions,InnerClasses,Signature,Deprecated,
                SourceFile,LineNumberTable,*Annotation*,EnclosingMethod
            </option>
            <!-- This option will save all original names in interfaces (without obfuscate). -->
            <option>-keepnames interface **</option>
            <!-- This option will save all original methods parameters in files defined in -keep sections, otherwise all parameter names will be obfuscate. -->
            <option>-keepparameternames</option>
            <!-- This option will save all original class files (without obfuscate) but obfuscate all in domain package. -->
            <option>-keep class !com.slm.proguard.example.spring.boot.domain.** { *; }</option>
            <!-- This option will save all original class files (without obfuscate) in service package -->
            <!--<option>-keep class com.slm.proguard.example.spring.boot.service { *; }</option> -->
            <!-- This option will save all original interfaces files (without obfuscate) in all packages. -->
            <option>-keep interface * extends * { *; }</option>
            <!-- This option will save all original defined annotations in all class in all packages. -->
            <option>-keepclassmembers class * {
                @org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired *;
                @org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Value *;
                }
            </option>
        </options>
        <libs>
            <!-- Include main JAVA library required. -->
            <lib>${java.home}/lib/rt.jar</lib>
            <!-- Include crypto JAVA library if necessary. -->
            <lib>${java.home}/lib/jce.jar</lib>
        </libs>
    </configuration>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>net.sf.proguard</groupId>
            <artifactId>proguard-base</artifactId>
            <version>6.0.3</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
</plugin>
```

right now during the Maven build it fails with the following error:

```
[proguard] Note: duplicate definition of library class [javax.el.ArrayELResolver]
 [proguard] Note: duplicate definition of library class [javax.el.BeanELResolver$1]
 [proguard] Note: duplicate definition of library class [javax.el.BeanELResolver$BeanProperties]
 [proguard] Note: duplicate definition of library class [javax.el.BeanELResolver$BeanProperty]
 [proguard] Note: duplicate definition of library class [javax.el.BeanELResolver]
 [proguard] Note: duplicate definition of library class [javax.el.BeanNameELResolver]
 [proguard] Note: duplicate definition of library class [javax.el.BeanNameResolver]
 [proguard] Note: duplicate definition of library class [javax.el.CompositeELResolver]
 [proguard] Note: duplicate definition of library class [javax.el.ELClass]
 [proguard] Note: duplicate definition of library class [javax.el.ELContext]
 [proguard] Note: duplicate definition of library class [javax.el.ELContextEvent]
 [proguard] Note: duplicate definition of library class [javax.el.ELContextListener]
 [proguard] Note: duplicate definition of library class [javax.el.ELException]
 [proguard] Note: duplicate definition of library class [javax.el.ELManager]
 [proguard] Note: duplicate definition of library class [javax.el.ELProcessor]
 [proguard] Note: duplicate definition of library class [javax.el.ELResolver]
 [proguard] Note: duplicate definition of library class [javax.el.EvaluationListener]
 [proguard] Note: duplicate definition of library class [javax.el.Expression]
 [proguard] Note: duplicate definition of library class [javax.el.ExpressionFactory]
 [proguard] Note: duplicate definition of library class [javax.el.FunctionMapper]
 [proguard] Note: duplicate definition of library class [javax.el.ImportHandler]
 [proguard] Note: duplicate definition of library class [javax.el.LambdaExpression]
 [proguard] Note: duplicate definition of library class [javax.el.ListELResolver]
 [proguard] Note: duplicate definition of library class [javax.el.MapELResolver]
 [proguard] Note: duplicate definition of library class [javax.el.MethodExpression]
 [proguard] Note: duplicate definition of library class [javax.el.MethodInfo]
 [proguard] Note: duplicate definition of library class [javax.el.MethodNotFoundException]
 [proguard] Note: duplicate definition of library class [javax.el.PropertyNotFoundException]
 [proguard] Note: duplicate definition of library class [javax.el.PropertyNotWritableException]
 [proguard] Note: duplicate definition of library class [javax.el.ResourceBundleELResolver]
 [proguard] Note: duplicate definition of library class [javax.el.StandardELContext$1]
 [proguard] Note: duplicate definition of library class [javax.el.StandardELContext]
 [proguard] Note: duplicate definition of library class [javax.el.StaticFieldELResolver]
 [proguard] Note: duplicate definition of library class [javax.el.TypeConverter]
 [proguard] Note: duplicate definition of library class [javax.el.ValueExpression]
 [proguard] Note: duplicate definition of library class [javax.el.ValueReference]
 [proguard] Note: duplicate definition of library class [javax.el.VariableMapper]
 [proguard] Reading library jar [C:\Users\Alexander\.m2\repository\javax\interceptor\javax.interceptor-api\1.2\javax.interceptor-api-1.2.jar]
 [proguard] Reading library jar [C:\Users\Alexander\.m2\repository\javax\inject\javax.inject\1\javax.inject-1.jar]
 [proguard] Reading library jar [C:\Users\Alexander\.m2\repository\javax\transaction\jta\1.1\jta-1.1.jar]
 [proguard] Reading library jar [C:\Users\Alexander\.m2\repository\org\apache\commons\commons-lang3\3.7\commons-lang3-3.7.jar]
 [proguard] Reading library jar [C:\Users\Alexander\.m2\repository\commons-validator\commons-validator\1.6\commons-validator-1.6.jar]
 [proguard] Reading library jar [C:\Users\Alexander\.m2\repository\commons-beanutils\commons-beanutils\1.9.2\commons-beanutils-1.9.2.jar]
 [proguard] Reading library jar [C:\Users\Alexander\.m2\repository\commons-digester\commons-digester\1.8.1\commons-digester-1.8.1.jar]
 [proguard] Reading library jar [C:\Users\Alexander\.m2\repository\commons-logging\commons-logging\1.2\commons-logging-1.2.jar]
 [proguard] Note: duplicate definition of library class [org.apache.commons.logging.impl.SimpleLog]
 [proguard] Note: duplicate definition of library class [org.apache.commons.logging.impl.NoOpLog]
 [proguard] Note: duplicate definition of library class [org.apache.commons.logging.LogFactory]
 [proguard] Note: duplicate definition of library class [org.apache.commons.logging.LogFactory$1]
 [proguard] Note: duplicate definition of library class [org.apache.commons.logging.LogFactory$2]
 [proguard] Note: duplicate definition of library class [org.apache.commons.logging.Log]
 [proguard] Reading library jar [C:\Users\Alexander\.m2\repository\commons-collections\commons-collections\3.2.2\commons-collections-3.2.2.jar]
 [proguard] Reading library jar [C:\Users\Alexander\.m2\repository\commons-io\commons-io\2.6\commons-io-2.6.jar]
 [proguard] Reading library jar [C:\Users\Alexander\.m2\repository\org\apache\commons\commons-compress\1.16.1\commons-compress-1.16.1.jar]
 [proguard] Reading library jar [C:\Users\Alexander\.m2\repository\org\objenesis\objenesis\2.6\objenesis-2.6.jar]
 [proguard] Reading library jar [C:\Users\Alexander\.m2\repository\org\apache\commons\commons-text\1.3\commons-text-1.3.jar]
 [proguard] Reading library jar [C:\Java\jdk1.8.0_171\jre\lib\rt.jar]
 [proguard] Note: duplicate definition of library class [javax.annotation.Generated]
 [proguard] Note: duplicate definition of library class [javax.annotation.PostConstruct]
 [proguard] Note: duplicate definition of library class [javax.annotation.PreDestroy]
 [proguard] Note: duplicate definition of library class [javax.annotation.Resource$AuthenticationType]
 [proguard] Note: duplicate definition of library class [javax.annotation.Resource]
 [proguard] Note: duplicate definition of library class [javax.annotation.Resources]
 [proguard] Note: duplicate definition of library class [javax.transaction.InvalidTransactionException]
 [proguard] Note: duplicate definition of library class [javax.transaction.TransactionRequiredException]
 [proguard] Note: duplicate definition of library class [javax.transaction.TransactionRolledbackException]
 [proguard] Note: duplicate definition of library class [javax.transaction.xa.XAException]
 [proguard] Note: duplicate definition of library class [javax.transaction.xa.XAResource]
 [proguard] Note: duplicate definition of library class [javax.transaction.xa.Xid]
 [proguard] Reading library jar [C:\Java\jdk1.8.0_171\jre\lib\jce.jar]
 [proguard] Note: there were 57 duplicate class definitions.
 [proguard]       (http://proguard.sourceforge.net/manual/troubleshooting.html#duplicateclass)
 [proguard] Warning: there were 2 classes in incorrectly named files.
 [proguard]          You should make sure all file names correspond to their class names.
 [proguard]          The directory hierarchies must correspond to the package hierarchies.
 [proguard]          (http://proguard.sourceforge.net/manual/troubleshooting.html#unexpectedclass)
 [proguard]          If you don't mind the mentioned classes not being written out,
 [proguard]          you could try your luck using the '-ignorewarnings' option.
 [proguard] Error: Please correct the above warnings first.
```

What am I doing wrong and how to fix it ?

Answer (score 0):

Output log is cut at the beginning so I don't see which package caused those two warnings,
but if you are using Spring then probably it's log4j causing problems.

You can fix it by adding

```
<option>-dontwarn **log4j**,**module-info</option>
```